# Android Authentication Activity with Fragments

Tags: java, android, authentication, layout

I have an `Activity` called AuthActivity and I would like all of my authentication `Fragments` to be in this `Activity`. I will have 4 `Fragments`: LoginFragment, RegisterFragment, ForgotPasswordFragment and RememberedLoginFragment. I currently only have the LoginFragment and I would like some feedback before I continue making the others. I would like some feedback on all of the code, Java and XML.

fragment_login.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/loginTopView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/loginCenterView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/loginLogo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_logo"
            android:contentDescription="@string/logo" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/loginBottomView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/loginEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:hint="@string/email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textColorHint="#AAFFFFFF" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/loginPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/loginEmail"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textColorHint="#AAFFFFFF" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/loginRememberMe"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/loginPassword"
            android:text="@string/remember_me" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/loginStayLoggedIn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/loginRememberMe"
            android:text="@string/stay_logged_in" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/loginButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/loginStayLoggedIn"
            android:text="@string/login"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/loginForgotPassword"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/loginButton"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="@string/forgot_password" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/loginRegisterLink"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="@string/register_link_text" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

LoginFragment.java:

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
    }

}
```

activity_auth.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_auth"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

AuthActivity.java:

```
public class AuthActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_auth);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }

        LoginFragment loginFragment = new LoginFragment();
        loginFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.activity_auth, loginFragment).commit();
```

Here is an image of the result:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Well, since there is hardly any Java code to review I'll review your xml code.

It is good practice to combine attributes that your layouts/views have in common in your /res/values/styles.xml file. F.e. :

```
<style name="LayoutStyleMatchParent">        
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
</style> 

<style name="LayoutStyleWrapContent">        
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
 </style>

<style name="LayoutStyleWide">        
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
 </style>

<style name="EditTextStyle" parent="LayoutStyleWide">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">#AAFFFFFF</item>
</style>

<style name="EditTextLogin" parent="EditTextStyle">
    <item name="android:hint">@string/email</item>
    <item name="android:inputType">textEmailAddress</item>
    <item name="android:layout_alignParentTop">true</item>
</style>

<style name="EditTextPassword" parent="EditTextStyle">
    <item name="android:hint">@string/password</item>
    <item name="android:inputType">textPassword</item>
    <item name="android:layout_below">@id/loginEmail</item>
</style>

<style name="CheckBoxRememberMe" parent="LayoutStyleWrapContent">
    <item name="android:layout_below">@id/loginPassword</item>
    <item name="android:text="@string/remember_me"</item>
</style>

<style name="CheckBoxStayLoggedIn" parent="LayoutStyleWrapContent">
    <item name="android:layout_below="@id/loginRememberMe"</item>
    <item name="android:text="@string/stay_logged_in"</item>
</style>
```

etc...

This minimizes code duplication and you can reuse/extend these styles in your other Fragments

So this part of your xml code :

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/loginEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:hint="@string/email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textColorHint="#AAFFFFFF" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/loginPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/loginEmail"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textColorHint="#AAFFFFFF" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/loginRememberMe"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/loginPassword"
        android:text="@string/remember_me" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/loginStayLoggedIn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/loginRememberMe"
        android:text="@string/stay_logged_in" />
```

then could look like this :

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/loginEmail"
        style="@style/EditTextLogin" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/loginPassword"
        style="@style/EditTextPassword" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/loginRememberMe"
        style="@style/CheckBoxRememberMe" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/loginStayLoggedIn"
        style="@style/CheckBoxStayLoggedIn" />
```